# Stream file to Github repo

Tags: git, github

Normally a file has to be on the filesystem, in order to be added to a git commit, etc.

```
git add $file
git commit -m "added $file"
git push
```

my question is - is there a way to stream a file to a remote git repo?

What that would probably mean - it never gets added to the local repo, it only gets added to the remote. Which is fine for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/). The idea of it is that you have "shims" (just metadata) of the files in the repo, and their data is stored elsewhere (like S3). The "shims" can be "materialized" into the real files as needed.

By default the ["basic transfer API"](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/api/basic-transfers.md) uses HTTP uploads/downloads, but you can also implement a ["custom transfer agent"](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/custom-transfers.md) and thus completely control how your file is stored/streamed.